# how to make jackson Include.NON_NULL works with spring4's @RestController?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I try it a lot way for 4 hour,is anyone know how to make it works?

I tried write these in my servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
                    <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

It does not work at all.
I read the source code of spring,and debug it in the eclipse.
The messageConverter which it used is the Object constructed by RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor#RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(List> messageConverters,ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager, List responseBodyAdvice)

And I trace the code, the above construct is called by RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#getDefaultReturnValueHandlers() which Method is called before set custom my messageConverter.
So the setting above is not work.

Oh my god, how could I make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Jackson 2.0 you can use @JsonInclude in your pojo.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Pojo{

}
```